# Twitter API authorization issue

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I've got the the bearer token, but keep getting a json error:
(401, '{\n  "title": "Unauthorized",\n  "type": "about:blank",\n  "status": 401,\n  "detail": "Unauthorized"\n}')

Here's the current code:

```
def create_headers(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    return headers

def create_url(keyword, start_date, end_date, max_results = 10):
    
    search_url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all" #Change to the endpoint you want to collect data from

    #change params based on the endpoint you are using
    query_params = {'query': keyword,
                    'start_time': start_date,
                    'end_time': end_date,
                    'max_results': max_results,
                    'tweet.fields': 'id,text,author_id,public_metrics,referenced_tweets,source',
                    'next_token': {}}
    return (search_url, query_params)



def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers, params, next_token = None):
    params['next_token'] = next_token   #params object received from create_url function
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, params = params)
    print("Endpoint Response Code: " + str(response.status_code))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()



#Inputs for the request
bearer_token = auth()
headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
keyword = "small business lang:en"
start_time = "2023-04-12T20:05:29.000Z"
end_time = "2023-04-19T20:05:29.908Z"
max_results = 10



url = create_url(keyword, start_time,end_time, max_results)
json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url[0], headers, url[1])
```

Comment: Are you certain your token is valid?

Comment: @JonSG everything looks normal, is there a way to test that? I made sure the app was assigned to a project on the Twitter side, is there another step I missed?

Comment: It looks "ok" to me and I use that endpoint on a regular basis. I know twitter is looking at removing "free" access to this api. Has this just recently stopped working for you?

Comment: This was my first time trying it, just tried it yesterday. Sounds like I may have missed the boat... Thanks for you help!